# IIS 7 Exact Match Rewrite

Tags: iis-7, rewrite

I'm trying to setup a rewrite for my site.  I've fiddled with this for days but can't get it to work right.

Here is what I'm looking for:

Original URL: **site.com/searchresults.aspx?categoryid=6**
Desired URL: **site.com/products/books/school**

In addition to this exact match, I have 50 more that don't have a pattern.  Do I need to setup the exact match rule for each of them, or is there a shorthand way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to post your rule as it exists for us to help you debug the exact match problem.

For this type of redirect you'll have to write explicit rules since there's no way for the rule engine to automatically resolve your query into a uri path (that's what the application should be doing).  If this is your own application I would suggest changing your routing rules or putting the redirect directly into the searchresults.aspx code.